# Symfony2 Upload file through service

Tags: php, symfony, upload, media

I'm still learning on Symfony2. But here I have an understanding issue with a media service I created for a project.

When I use the Media Controller, the file is uploaded and my Media entity is complete with the infos from the file and stuffs I need.

But when I try to use this MediaBundle as a service with the Handler I setted up, it doesn't work.
The ImageFormHandler is called, but nothing is uploaded. And I don't understand why and the ImageForm isn't valid at all.

I don't want to use any SF2 Bundles in order to learn about Symfony2 and also because they most of the time do more than what we need.

I hope you could help me. 
Thank you so much in advance.

Sorry : it's also my very first post on StackOverflow.

Infopro/MediaBundle/DefaultController.php

```
namespace Infopro\MediaBundle\Controller;

use Infopro\MediaBundle\Form\Handler\ImageFormHandler;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Upload forms
     *
     * @Route("/upload", name="media_upload_index")
     * @Template("InfoproMediaBundle:Default:index.html.twig")
     * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $formImage = $this->get('media.image.form');
        $formPdf   = $this->get('media.pdf.form');

        $this->get('media.image.form.handler')->process($request);
        $this->get('media.pdf.form.handler')->process($request);

        return array(
            'formImage' => $formImage->createView(),
            'formPdf'   => $formPdf->createView()
        );
    }

    /**
     * Upload forms
     *
     * @Route("/uploadimage/", name="media_upload_image")
     * @Route("/uploadimage/{uploadedto}/{class}", name="media_upload_image_params")
     * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request
     * @param string $uploadedto
     * @param string $class
     * @return array
     */
    public function uploadImageAction(Request $request,$uploadedto = null, $class = null)
    {
        /** @var ImageFormHandler $mediaImageFormHandler */
        $imageFormHandler = $this->get('media.image.form.handler');
        $media = $imageFormHandler->process($request);
        if($media !== null)
        {
            return new JsonResponse(['success' => true,'media' => $media, 'uploadedto' => $uploadedto, 'class' => $class]);
        }

        return new JsonResponse(['success' => false,'uploadedto' => $uploadedto, 'class' => $class]);
    }
}
```

MediaBundle/Entity.php

```
namespace Infopro\MediaBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Uploadable\Fixture\Entity\Image;


/**
 * Media
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="mediatheque")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Media
{
    static $defaultMimeType = 'image/jpeg';
    static $defaultType     = 0;
    static $defaultHeight   = 1000;
    static $defaultWidth    = 1000;
    static $rootDir = null;
    static $widthInImageSize = 0;
    static $heightInImageSize = 1;
    static $defaultDirectory = 'default';

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="original_name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $originalName;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="mime_type", type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $mimeType;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="size", type="integer")
     * @Assert\Type(type="integer")
     */
    private $size;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="height", type="integer")
     * @Assert\Type(type="integer")
     */
    private $height;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="width", type="integer")
     * @Assert\Type(type="integer")
     */
    private $width;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="integer")
     * @Assert\Type(type="integer")
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime")
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="image", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     *
     * @Assert\Image(
     *     maxSize="1000000",
     *     maxWidth = 1000,
     *     maxHeight = 1000,
     *     mimeTypes = {
     *          "image/jpeg",
     *          "image/jpg",
     *          "image/gif",
     *          "image/png",
     *      }
     * )
     */
    private $image;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\File(
     *      maxSize="300000000",
     *      mimeTypes = {"application/pdf"},
     *  )
     * @ORM\Column(name="pdf", type="string", length=255,nullable=true)
     */
    private $pdf;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="uploaded_to", type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $uploadedTo;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Media
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set originalName
     *
     * @param string $originalName
     *
     * @return Media
     */
    public function setOriginalName($originalName)
    {
        $this->originalName = $originalName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get originalName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getOriginalName()
    {
        return $this->originalName;
    }

    /**
     * Set mimeType
     *
     * @param string $mimeType
     *
     * @return Media
     */
    public function setMimeType($mimeType)
    {
        $this->mimeType = $mimeType;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get mimeType
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMimeType()
    {
        return $this->mimeType;
    }

    /**
     * Set size
     *
     * @param integer $size
     *
     * @return Media
     */
    public function setSize($size)
    {
        $this->size = $size;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get size
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getSize()
    {
        return $this->size;
    }

    /**
     * Set height
     *
     * @param integer $height
     *
     * @return Media
     */
    public function setHeight($height)
    {
        $this->height = $height;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get height
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getHeight()
    {
        return $this->height;
    }

    /**
     * Set width
     *
     * @param integer $width
     *
     * @return Media
     */
    public function setWidth($width)
    {
        $this->width = $width;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get width
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getWidth()
    {
        return $this->width;
    }

    /**
     * Set type
     *
     * @param integer $type
     *
     * @return Media
     */
    public function setType($type)
    {
        $this->type = $type;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get type
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $createdAt
     *
     * @return Media
     */
    public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set updatedAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updatedAt
     *
     * @return Media
     */
    public function setUpdatedAt($updatedAt)
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updatedAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUpdatedAt()
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set image
     *
     * @param string $image
     *
     * @return Media
     */
    public function setImage($image)
    {
        $this->image = $image;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get image
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    /**
     * Set pdf
     *
     * @param string $pdf
     *
     * @return Media
     */
    public function setPdf($pdf)
    {
        $this->pdf = $pdf;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get pdf
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPdf()
    {
        return $this->pdf;
    }


    public function uploadImage()
    {
        if($this->image !== null) {
            $newName = uniqid() . $this->name . '.' . $this->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $this->setName($newName);
            $this->setMimeType($this->image->getClientMimeType());
            $this->setType(self::$defaultType);
            $this->setHeight(self::$defaultHeight);
            $this->setWidth(self::$defaultWidth);
            $this->setOriginalName($this->image->getClientOriginalName());
            $this->setSize($this->image->getClientSize());

            $file = $this->image->move($this->getImageUploadRootDir(), $newName);
            $this->setDimension($file);
        } else {
            $this->setName('noimage'.uniqid());
            $this->setOriginalName('noimage');
        }
    }

    private function setDimension($file)
    {
        $dimension = getimagesize($file->getPathName());
        $this->setHeight($dimension[1]);
        $this->setWidth($dimension[0]);
    }

    public function uploadZip()
    {
        $this->pdf->move($this->getZipUploadRootDir(), uniqid().'.pdf');
    }

    protected function getImageUploadRootDir()
    {
        return self::$rootDir.'/images/'.$this->getUploadedTo();
    }

    protected function getZipUploadRootDir()
    {
        return self::$rootDir.'/zip';
    }

    public function setUploadRootDir($rootDir)
    {
        if(self::$rootDir === null)
        {
            self::$rootDir = $rootDir;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $uploadedTo
     * @return Media
     */
    public function setUploadedTo($uploadedTo)
    {
        $this->uploadedTo = $uploadedTo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUploadedTo()
    {
        return $this->uploadedTo;
    }
}
```

Infopro/MediaBundle/Resources/config/services.yml

```
parameters:
    media.image.form.type.class:    Infopro\MediaBundle\Form\Type\ImageFormType
    media.image.form.handler.class: Infopro\MediaBundle\Form\Handler\ImageFormHandler
    media.pdf.form.type.class:      Infopro\MediaBundle\Form\Type\PdfFormType
    media.pdf.form.handler.class:   Infopro\MediaBundle\Form\Handler\PdfFormHandler
    media.entity.class:             Infopro\MediaBundle\Entity\Media

services:     
    media.image.form.type:
        class: %media.image.form.type.class%
        arguments:
            - %media.entity.class%
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: media }

    media.image.form:
        factory_method: create
        factory_service: form.factory
        class: Symfony\Component\Form\Form
        arguments:
            - @media.image.form.type

    media.image.form.handler:
        class: %media.image.form.handler.class%
        scope: request
        arguments: 
            - @media.image.form
            - @doctrine.orm.entity_manager
            - @session
            - @router
            - %media.root.dir%

    media.pdf.form.type:
        class: %media.pdf.form.type.class%
        arguments:
            - %media.entity.class%
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: media_zip }

    media.pdf.form:
        factory_method: create
        factory_service: form.factory
        class: Symfony\Component\Form\Form
        arguments:
            - @media.pdf.form.type

    media.pdf.form.handler:
        class: %media.pdf.form.handler.class%
        scope: request
        arguments: 
            - @media.pdf.form
            - @doctrine.orm.entity_manager
            - @session
            - @router
            - %media.root.dir%
```

Infopro/MediaBundle/Form/Handler/ImageFormHandler.php

```
<?php

namespace Infopro\MediaBundle\Form\Handler;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Infopro\MediaBundle\Entity\Media;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Form;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;

class ImageFormHandler
{
    const heightInImageSize = 1;
    const widthInImageSize = 0;
    protected $form;
    protected $em;
    protected $sessions;
    protected $router;
    protected $rootDir;

    protected $dimension = [];


    public function __construct(Form $form, EntityManager $em, Session $session, Router $router, $rootDir)
    {
        $this->form = $form;
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->rootDir = $rootDir;
    }

    /**
     * Process image form
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Media|null|string
     */
    public function process(Request $request)
    {
        $media = null;
        $media = $this->form->getData();

        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
            $this->form->handleRequest($request);
            if ($this->form->isValid()) {
                /** @var Media $media */
                $media = $this->form->getData();
                $uploadedto =  $request->get('uploadedto') === null ? 'front' : $request->get('uploadedto');
                $media->setUploadedTo($uploadedto);
                $media->setUploadRootDir($this->rootDir);
                $media->uploadImage();
                $this->em->persist($media);
                $this->em->flush();
                $this->session->getFlashBag()->add('info', 'Image uploaded to Media Library');
            }
        }

        if($media !== null)
        {
            return $media->getName();
        }

        return $media;

    }

    public function uploadImage(Request $request)
    {
        $medias = [];
        foreach ($request->files as $file) {
            /** @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $file */
            $this->setDimension($file);
            $media = new Media();
            $media->setImage($file);
            $media->setUploadedTo($request->get('uploadedto'));
            $media->setMimeType($file->getClientMimeType());
            $media->setName($this->getUnuglifyName($file));
            $media->setUploadRootDir($this->rootDir);
            $media->setWidth($this->getWidth());
            $media->setHeight($this->getHeight());
            $media->uploadImage();
            $this->em->persist($media);
            $this->em->flush();
            array_push($medias, $media->getId());
        }

        return $medias;
    }

    /**
     * @param UploadedFile $file
     */
    private function setDimension(UploadedFile $file)
    {
        $this->dimension = getimagesize($file->getPathName());
    }

    private function getWidth()
    {
        return $this->dimension[self::widthInImageSize];
    }

    private function getHeight()
    {
        return $this->dimension[self::heightInImageSize];
    }

    /**
     * @param UploadedFile $file
     * @return string
     */
    private function getUnuglifyName(UploadedFile $file)
    {
        return uniqid() . $file->getClientOriginalName() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    }
}
```

Infopro/AppBundle/DemoController.php

```
/**
 * @Method({"GET"})
 * @Route("/image", name="image_upload")
 * @Template("InfoproAppBundle:Default:image.html.twig")
 */
public function imageAction()
{
    $page = new Page();
    $form = $this->createForm(new PageType(), $page);
    $formImage = $this->get('media.image.form');

    return ['form' => $form->createView(), 'formImage' => $formImage->createView()];
}

/**
 * @Method({"POST"})
 * @Route("/image", name="image_upload_post")
 * @Template("InfoproAppBundle:Default:image.html.twig")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return array
 */
public function imagePostAction(Request $request)
{
    $page = new Page();
    $form = $this->createForm(new PageType(), $page);

    $imageFormHandler = $this->get('media.image.form.handler');
    $media = $imageFormHandler->process($request);
    $formImage = $this->get('media.image.form');
    var_dump($media);

    if($media === null) {
        return ['form' => $form->createView(), 'formImage' => $formImage->createView()];
    }

    return ['coucou' => 'test'];
}
```

Infopro/AppBundle/Form/Type/PageType.php

```
class PageType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('title', 'text', ['label' => 'Title', 'required' => true]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(['compound' => true]);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'page';
    }
}
```

Infopro/DatabaseBundle/Entity/Page.php

```
namespace Infopro\DatabaseBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Page
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="pages")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Infopro\DatabaseBundle\Entity\PageRepository")
 */
class Page
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_pages", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="label", type="string", length=45)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="image_header", type="string", length=300)
     */
    private $imageHeader;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="image_header_reabo", type="string", length=300)
     */
    private $imageHeaderRenew;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="url_site", type="string", length=300)
     */
    private $url;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     *
     * @return Page
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set imageHeader
     *
     * @param string $imageHeader
     *
     * @return Page
     */
    public function setImageHeader($imageHeader)
    {
        $this->imageHeader = $imageHeader;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get imageHeader
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getImageHeader()
    {
        return $this->imageHeader;
    }

    /**
     * Set imageHeaderRenew
     *
     * @param string $imageHeaderRenew
     *
     * @return Page
     */
    public function setImageHeaderRenew($imageHeaderRenew)
    {
        $this->imageHeaderRenew = $imageHeaderRenew;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get imageHeaderRenew
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getImageHeaderRenew()
    {
        return $this->imageHeaderRenew;
    }

    /**
     * Set url
     *
     * @param string $url
     *
     * @return Page
     */
    public function setUrl($url)
    {
        $this->url = $url;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUrl()
    {
        return $this->url;
    }
}
```